# defend against LOIC Hive Mind attack

Tags: denial-of-service, ddos

Other than client puzzles, what are some things a website can do to defend itself against a
LOIC Hive Mind attack?

The Low Orbit Ion Cannon (LOIC) is an attack tool which features a user-friendly GUI as well
as an option to voluntarily add yourself to a botnet controlled via an IRC channel.

Comment: EECS 388 rox my socks.

Answer (score 6):

Akamai and Cloudflare provide [DDoS protection services](https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos) which will disperse traffic using DNS load balancing, blacklist bots, and filter attacks before they reach your server(s).

LOIC produces an HTTP GET flood, this is not an advanced DoS technique but rather a simple script to carry out a trivial attack.  Any worthwhile DDoS prevention product should solve this basic attack.  Until a certain point, of course, and then no one can solve it.

Comment: Isn't it better to tell the author how to mitigate the attack himself rather than telling him to take out the credit card and let a third-party do it?

Comment: @AndréDaniel, How to mitigate it yourself: take out the credit card and buy a whole lot of servers and load balancers, behind one or several high-bandwidth connections.  The basic technique for mitigating a DDoS attack is to have infrastructure capable of handling more traffic than the attacker is capable of producing.

Comment: @Mark it depends on the attack. In this case the attack floods GET requests in order to make the server process each request and waste resources (especially if the page is a dynamic PHP/Ruby/whatever page and not a static one), but some firewall rules and/or rate limiting will be enough in most cases, unless the attackers totally overload the server's bandwidth in which case indeed you can't do much without extra bandwidth and servers.

Comment: @user42178 The only way to mitigate it is with large amounts of hardware and big pipes. Either yours or someone else's.